# Angular toggle between ng-show and ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide, angularjs-ng-show

What it does is that it takes the input of 'Github username' and uses that to display other values. It hits the API and catches the response in a variable called 'user'. What I want is that when I enter a non-existent username, it should show the 'table', 'error', and a few other parts of the UI. When I enter a valid username, it should hide those parts again.

Basically, I want to be able to toggle between ng-show and ng-hide. I know the solution is going to be something really simple but my brain has shut down and I have spent the last 3 hours trying different permutations and failed all.

Go on and solve.. Lest I am going to have nightmares about this, literally. This code is haunting me already.

Cheers!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1><div>

    <h1 ng-show="user">{{ message }}</h1>

  </div></h1>
  <div ng-show="username">
  User handle: {{ username }}</div><br/>
  <div ng-show="user">{{ error }}</div>
  <form name="searchUser">

<input type = "search" placeholder = "username to find" ng-model="username">
<input type="submit" value = "Search" ng-click="search(username)">
    Order: <select ng-model="repoSortSelector" ng-show="user">
      <option value="+name">Name</option>
      <option value="-stargazers_count">Star</option>
      <option value="+language">Language</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <h2>{{ user.login }}</h2>
  <img ng-src="{{ user.avatar_url }}" title="{{ user.login }}">
  <table ng-show="user">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Stars</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos | orderBy: repoSortSelector">
      <td>{{ repo.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ repo.stargazers_count | number }}</td>
      <td>{{ repo.language }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

and Script

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['controllers']);
angular.module('controllers', []).controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {


  $scope.message = "Search User"
  var onComplete = function(response) {

    $scope.user = response.data;
    if(user.message=="Not Found"){

      $scope.user=0;

    }
    $http.get($scope.user.repos_url)
      .then(onRepos, onReposError)

  };
  var onRepos = function(response) {

    $scope.repos = response.data;
    console.log($scope.repos);
    $scope.repoSortSelector = "-stargazers_count";
  }

  var onReposError = function(reason) {


    console.log(reason);

  }

  var onError = function(reason) {
    $scope.error = "Could not find the result. Please try something else! "

  }

  // $scope.message = "Hello, Angular!"

  $scope.search = function(username) {
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
      .then(onComplete, onError);
  }



});
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think `$scope.user` should be set as a boolean not `$scope.user=0`

So when `$scope.user ===  true` or `ng-show = "user"`(or YES we found a user) we show the related element for when user exists.

when `$scope.user === false` or `ng-show= "!user"` in our HTML we display the element relevant to the user not existing.

If `user` needs to remain an int for some reason, create a new variable to throw into the `scope` based on the value of `user` and use it to `show/hide`.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide  this is a pretty nifty guide on ways to use `show/hide`

As you've only two actions (AFAICS) then you won't run into any problems, things start getting way more complicated when you're trying to `show/hide` 3 or more things based on a couple of variables.

Answer (score 0):

You code is confusing to read, especially your `then` callbacks spread at random places.
Maybe you could rewrite more like this :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['controllers']);

// Here better use dependency injection using the inline Array Notation
angular.module('controllers', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.message = 'Search User';

    $scope.search = function (username) {
        $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username)
       .then(function (response) {
           // I think response.data is null if user is not found so you can
           // directly use $scope.user to check whether to display data
           $scope.user = response.data;

           // Return a promise here
           return $http.get($scope.user.repos_url);
       })
       .then(function (response) {
           $scope.repos = response.data;
           $scope.repoSortSelector = '-stargazers_count';
       })
       .catch(function (err) {
            $scope.error = err;
            console.log(err);
       });
   }
}]);
```

I put some suggestions in comments.

Also, always use `"`or `'`, not both (I prefer the latter) and use triple equals `===` for equality.

Simply check for `ng-show="user"`to show or hide parts or your UI.